# AWS CDK Step Functions SNS Task - input path parameter injected into message

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to make a step function workflow for processing transactions and broadcasting a message when the transaction has been successful.
Came up with something like this:

```js
new SnsPublish(this, 'publish-successful-transaction', {
            message: TaskInput.fromText(`transaction #${TaskInput.fromJsonPathAt('$.transactionId')} was processed successfully!`),
            resultPath: '$.message',
            topic: this.notification.topic
        })
```

However, predictably `.fromJsonPath()` returns an instance of `TaskInput` which results in the normal object-in-a-string behaviour i.e `[Object object]`.

I tried getting the `value` property from the `TaskInput` instance but that results in an error:

```
Error: Field references must be the entire string, cannot concatenate them
(found 'transaction #${Token[transactionId.269]} was processed successfully!')
```

Is there a way to have a custom text message with injected input path parameter? Can't seem to find anything on this even though it seems like quite a straightforward use case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<Edit> Turns out there is a simple, one-line solution after all:

```js
message: sfn.TaskInput.fromJsonPathAt("States.Format('transaction {} was processed successfully!', $.transactionId)")
```

The answer's original options are valid but more verbose </Edit>

---

Step Functions have a `States.Format` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) to interpolate strings.  <s>But because intrinsic functions aren't accepted in all fields (including not in `SnsPublish.message`), the solution is a bit less straightforward than you might hope.</s>

First, the formatting.  There are two equivalent CDK syntaxes for intrinsic functions:

```js
// produce identical State Machine JSON output:
{
  // State Machine Language JSON Syntax - DON'T FORGET .$ SUFFIX IN THE KEY
  'myMessage.$' "States.Format('transaction {} was processed successfully!', $.transactionId)",
  // JsonPath helpers - CDK only
  sameMessage: sfn.JsonPath.format('transaction {} was processed successfully!', sfn.JsonPath.stringAt('$.transactionId'))
}
```

<s>Next, you have two options to wire things up:</s>

##### Option 1: `sfn.Pass` + `tasks.SnsPublish`

Add a `Pass` task to format the message and use the result in`SnsPublish`'s message property:

```js
const formatMessage = new sfn.Pass(this, 'formatMessage', {
  parameters: { 'message.$': "States.Format('transaction {} was processed successfully!', $.transactionId)", },
  resultPath: '$.formatted',
});

const snsPublish = new tasks.SnsPublish(this, 'SnsPublish', {
  topic: this.notification.topic,
  message: sfn.TaskInput.fromJsonPathAt('$.formatted.message'),
});
```

##### <s>Option 2: `tasks.CallAwsService`</s>

The `parameters` property of the generic `CallAwsService` task can handle intrinsic functions.   Format and publish in a single task state:

```js
const snsPublish2 = new tasks.CallAwsService(this, 'SnsPublish2', {
  service: 'sns',
  action: 'publish',
  parameters: {
    TopicArn: this.notification.topic.topicArn,
    'Message.$': "States.Format('transaction {} was processed successfully!', $.transactionId)",
  },
  iamResources: [this.notification.topic.topicArn],
});
```

Comment: @Exanubes.com FYI I discovered a simple working solution. Answer edited.

Comment: Looks good, thanks a lot :)